# Error: extent not found. When booting from btrfs using grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, btrfs

I recently attempted to migrate from ext4 to btrfs,
made the @ and @home subvolumes, copied over everything to those subvolumes,
chroot into the installation and run `mkinitcpio - P` and grub install and update grub,

tried to boot and I am getting Error: extent not found. Press any key to continue... when booting,
if I press any key then I see some acpi errors (that always show when booting normally also) and then system freezes,

I checked the btrfs fs for errors `sudo btrfs check /dev/nvme0n1p5` but no errors,
don't see any other threads anywhere mention this error,

here is my grub.cfg entry:

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-1790bd87-8ede-4e60-bee0-acb105ec23f1' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod btrfs
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1790bd87-8ede-4e60-bee0-acb105ec23f1
    linux    /@/boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen root=UUID=1790bd87-8ede-4e60-bee0-acb105ec23f1 rw rootflags=subvol=@ 
    initrd  /@/boot/amd-ucode.img /@/boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img}
```

I can read from any file in btrfs fs from grub console so don't see why its not able to boot from it.

Let me know if any other info is needed, don't see any issues with the grub config above that stands out.